# K-theory as elliptic complexes

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles, k-theory

I would like to learn the theorem which states that K-theory defined in terms of vector bundles is isomorphic to the so called *compactly supported complexes* (those are complexes of vector bundles over locally compact space $X$ of the form $0 \to E_1 \to E_2 \to ... \to E_n \to 0$ where this sequence is exact except for some compact set $A \subset X$). I would be happy with the proof from which it is clear how the maps establishing isomorphism look like. I would be grateful for pointing me some references.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you should check out definition 9.23, and propositions 9.24, 9.25 in chapter I of Lawson and Michelsohn's *Spin Geometry*.

Comment: I strongly recommend Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro's Clifford Modules, Part II, for a start.